# raphael js Pan functionality using raphael-pan-zoom more than 9

Tags: raphael, pan

I love your plugin! the zoom worked perfectly, but I need more than 9 times zoom, is it possible?

Thanks,
Julio

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to post this somewhere more specific? I'm guessing it hasn't reached whoever you expected to be talking to.